# Google Maps Control for ASP.NET by Shabdar isn't working

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, webforms

I found a realy nice [Google Maps Control for ASP.NET](http://www.shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html) and I downloaded the latest version (1.9.3) and tried it (it works fine), after following the tutorial, I copied the files and then I got many nonsense error messages.

For example I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'ScriptManagerProxy' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

at this line

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAPIKey"] %>'></script>
```

I don't know what else should I write here, it's very easy to reproducate, just try to add the files and use the control in an ASP.NET Web Forms application.

How can I get this to work?

### EDIT

**1st : I fixed the missing assembly reference error**
In the `GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx` file I modified this line:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

and the new line now looks like this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    Namespace="System.Web" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

**2nd : I set the build action for each file**
File: *Build Action*
cGoogleMap.cs: *Compile*
GService.cs: *Compile*
GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx: *Content*
GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx.cs: *Content*
GService.asmx: *Content*
**Errors**
Now I get 9 error messages but all of them are the same:

> The type 'GoogleObject' exists in both 'PhoneTracker, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and '4_App_Code,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

but I can't find the duplicate one. I searched for `class GoogleObject` in the `Entire Solution` and I got one result.

### EDIT 2019.01.04

I moved everything to `GoogleMap` folder and now I get an error message: `hidEventName` doesn't exists in the current context, use the navigation bar to switch context. I read about this error, but I have only one front end file, so I cant understand this error.

Comment: Is your project a website or a web application? My guess is that the issue is how you reference the `System.Web.UI` assembly.

Comment: It's a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the **Google Map Control** (GMC) project is a **Web Site Project** and **my project** is a **Web Application** I have to convert the GMC to web application, after that I able to use it. I done it by following [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/) guide.